# Update ActivatedRoute query params not working - Angular

Tags: angular

I need to update my query params according to the selected filters (goroco and environment) and merge them with this query **http://localhost:4200/project?projectId=1**.
I try this :

```
/**
   * Refresh query params
   * @param gorocoId 
   * @param environmentId 
   */
  setFindDataChecklistRoute(gorocoId: number, environmentId: number) {
    const queryParams: Params = { gorocoId: gorocoId, environmentId: environmentId };
    console.log(queryParams)
    this.router.navigate(
      [], 
      {
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
        queryParams: queryParams,
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
      }
    );
  }
```

Console.log return **{gorocoId: 4, environmentId: 1}**

But I got this in my url: **http://localhost:4200/project?projectId=1&gorocoId=6**

Only **gorocoId** work, not **environmentId**...

Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you share the **this.activatedRoute** result?

Comment: this.activatedRoute queryParams log -> queryParams: {projectId: "1", gorocoId: "3"} and -> _routerState: RouterStateSnapshot {_root: TreeNode, url: "/project?projectId=1&gorocoId=3"}

Comment: Could you please share the code of route file?

Comment: I fixed my problem, I would overwrite the value in a sub-function...It's working fine now, thanks for help